# The program would not end and show the output when it must

Tags: c++

I cannot understand the reason behind it but it would not end when the input is -1 or the output is -1.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

const int limit = 40;

struct fraction
{
    int numenator = 0;
    int dumenator = 0;
};

class FractionClass
{
public:

    double answer = 0;
    double sentinel = 0;
    bool right = true;
    double count = 0;
    vector<int> answers;

    void readfraction()
    {
        cout << "Input the first number: ";
        cin >> fir;

        if (fir == -1)
        {
            right = false;
        }

        cout << "Input the second number: ";
        cin >> sec;


        answer = fir / sec;

        if (answer == -1)
        {
            right = false;
        }

        answers.push_back(answer);
    }

    void printfraction()
    {
        for (int answer : answers) cout << "Answer: " << answer;
    }

private:
    double fir, sec;
};


int main()
{
    FractionClass bill;

    while (bill.right == true)
    {
        bill.readfraction();
        cout << endl;
    }

    bill.printfraction();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This is the code. I wanted it to end and display the output once the first input fir or answer the output is -1.I think that the problem is in the while loop.I am not sure. Any help is appreciated.

My wanted output

Enter the fractions: -

Fraction #1: 2

Fraction #1: 5

Fraction #2: 8

Fraction #2: 3

Fraction #3: 2

Fraction #3: -1

Fraction #4: 4

Fraction #4: -9

Fraction #5: -1

---

Result Are The Followings: -
Fraction #1: 0.4

Fraction #2: 2.6666667

Fraction #3: -2

Fraction #4: -0.4444444

Comment: Please show a minimal input and actual vs. expected output.

Comment: `first = fir;`?? That is just the beginning of your problems. You will not get the expected result (fraction) since you're doing integer division.

Comment: Are you intending to overwrite every element of `arrays` each time, or do you mean to keep old answers there?

Comment: @Caleth I want it to keep the old answers. Eg Input ten names and then after all the names are inputted It will output all the ten names

Comment: Then you probably *don't* want `for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) { arrays[i] = answer; }`, instead e.g. `int answer_count = 0;` ... `arrays[answer_count++] = answer;`. Or much better `std::vector<int> answers;` ... `answers.push_back(answer);`

Comment: @Caleth I have tried the count++ from before but the answer was still 0 and I am not that good with vectors.I have modified the code it is still 0.

Comment: `printfraction` would need loop to count, rather than limit, and not be reading the space after the last answer

Comment: @Caleth I did not quite get that.Did you mean to create a loop in print fraction func and do not use i<limit;. and what about the final part relating to the spaces.I did not understand it

Comment: You start with 40 zeroes. If you read in 3 fractions, you'll have 3 answers followed by 37 zeros. Incrementing `count` in the printing will print one of those zeroes. Yes, use a loop but with `i < count` not `i < limit`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198950/discussion-between-caleth-and-ball-rall).

Comment: @Caleth thanks for the help.Could you give me an idea of the duration required for me to learn how to develop an app or a software as a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you do'nt need the num and dum variables in your main function, when you don't use them there:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

const int limit = 40;

struct fraction
{
    int numenator = 0;
    int dumenator = 0;
};

class FractionClass
{
public:

    int arrays[limit] = {};
    int answer = 0;
    int sentinel = 0;
    bool right = true;

    void readfraction()
    {
        cout << "Input the first number: ";
        cin >> fir;

        if (fir == -1)
        {
            right = false;
            return;
        }

        cout << "Input the second number: ";
        cin >> sec;


        answer = fir / sec;

        if (answer == -1)
        {
            right = false;
            return;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
        {
            arrays[i] = answer;
        }

    }

    void printfraction()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
        {
            cout << "Answer: " << arrays[i];
        }

    }

private:
    int fir, sec;
};


int main()
{
    FractionClass bill;

    while (bill.right == true)
    {
        bill.readfraction();
        cout << endl;
    }

    bill.printfraction();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Second you assign `first = fir` after you read your input in `first`. `fir` is never initialized, so it is undefined behaviour. The same applies to `second` and `sec`. Remember the left value gets assigned with the value on the right, not in the other direction!

If you really want ro return after the first value = -1 you should add a return statement in the if-clause.
Second you never reach the else-clause in main, because you break the while loop when right is set to false. I think you should print the output outside the loop. I don't understand your code, or what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: thanks fixed that but then the output was not being outputted so I modify the code and now the output is bunch of zeros.Can you help me out with that.Sorry was a bit distracted so I did not notice the fir=first.Thanks